# Jupyter Notebook with Active Directory authentication

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, active-directory, jupyter

I am trying to create a Jupyter Notebook server on Windows Server 2019, it is easy using Python and running `$ jupyter notebook`, the problem is I would like to add Active Directory Authentication, maybe like a reverse proxy or something like that, I tried this [tutorial](https://serverfault.com/questions/352647/restrict-access-to-iis-site-to-an-ad-group) but unfortunately it didn't work.

May someone help me on this?